# Django: have admin take image file but store it as a base64 string

Tags: python, django, image, django-models, base64

I was tasked with creating an admin view such that a user could input an image file, which however would be stored as a base64 string as a model field rather than exist in a static files dir on our server.

I'm unclear on how exactly this process would be done, should I be intercepting the POST request from the admin view and pre-processing it to be stored in the field? Should I be overwriting the save method of the base form? I'm a little confused by the different methods as I'm new to Django and have been unable to produce a working result.

Here's my setup:

**`models.py`**

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    logo = models.TextField()
```

**`admin.py`**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product 

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('logo',)

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

**`misc.py`**

```
#how i'd process an image?
from PIL import Image
from base64 import b64encode

def image_to_b64(image_file):
    imgdata = Image(image_file)
    encoded = b64encode(open(imgdata, 'rb'))
    return encoded
```

Comment: if you can accept add a logo_file(ImageField) to you Product,it will be sample by override save method in you model or form in admin.

Comment: @Ykh i'm attempting to not have the image saved to the server at all; can you provide a working example of how that would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    logo = models.TextField()
    logo_image = models.ImageFiled(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='logo')


def image_to_b64(image_file):
    import base64
    with open(image_file.path, "rb") as f:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(f.read())
        return encoded_string

from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, m2m_changed


@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def create_base64_str(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.logo = image_to_b64(instance.logo_image)
        instance.logo_image.delete()
        instance.save()
```

Comment: thanks for this; the second series of imports and the `create_base64_str` function should live in the models file? can you give a brief on how this is working?

Comment: 'create_base64_str ' doesn't need to live in model.py,if you want to remove this function to signals.py, you must add 'from .signals import create_base64_str' to your model.py or view.py even you don't need it.this function will be called after you Product instance create by admin or other interface,when a new product instance is created,i convert logo_image to base64 and save base64 to logo(TextField),then delete the useless logo_image.More info about signals see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/

Comment: this worked PERFECTLY. thank you so much for this and for opening my eyes to the world of signals! i did notice that for some reason this wouldn't work when I was editing an existing object, is that because post_save only handles post_save of new objects? or is that a bug? thanks so much again for the help.

Comment: ah; perhaps this has to do with the `if created` handle you have in the `create_base64_str` function because it already exists?

Comment: i'm getting the error: `ValueError at /admin/catalog/product/15/change/
The 'logo_image' attribute has no file associated with it.` still. i guess becuase after we run create_base64_str we delete the filepath. but shouldn't editing and then saving create a new one?

Comment: try don't delete logo_image after image_to_b64